# Projection with asynchronous programming

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm introducing asynchronous programming to my existing code base and having some trouble with calling Select() on the result of GetStudents() - the error message received is as follows "`Task<List<ApplicationUser>>` does not contain a defintion for Select". I think it'll be due to incorrect syntax, but any guidance would be appreciated - thanks.

```
   public async Task<List<ApplicationUser>> GetStudents()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => _context.Users.ToList());
    }


    public async Task<StudentIndexViewModel> CreateStudentRegisterViewModel()
    {
        var model = new StudentIndexViewModel();
        var students = await _studentRepo.GetStudents().
            Select(x => new StudentViewModel
            {
                Forename = x.Forename,
                Surname = x.Surname
            }).ToListAsync();

        model.Students = students;

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: You need to split it up into two lines, do the `var studentsResult = await _studentRepo.GetStudents();` and the next line `var students = studentsResult.Select(...)`. Or do what SLaks says and add parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was mentioned, the error comes from trying to call `Select` on a `Task<T>`, which is not valid. However, the problem is much bigger than that. The code is currently getting the entire table from the database just to get a few values from the result **in-memory**. This is a waste of processing time in both the database and the application server.
Not only that, but also using a thread pool thread just to wait on an I/O operation is another waste.

Overall, the code should be something like this.

```
public async Task<List<ApplicationUser>> GetApplicationUsersAsync()
{
    // use Entity Framework properly with ToListAsync
    // this returns the entire table
    return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<List<StudentViewModel>> GetStudentsAsync()
{
    // use Entity Framework properly with ToListAsync
    return await _context.Users
        // this only returns the 2 needed properties
        .Select(x => new StudentViewModel
        {
            Forename = x.Forename,
            Surname = x.Surname
        })
        .ToListAsync();
}


public async Task<StudentIndexViewModel> CreateStudentRegisterViewModel()
{
    var model = new StudentIndexViewModel();
    model.Students = await _studentRepo.GetStudentsAsync();

    return model;
}
```

Comment: You can elide the async/await in both the first two methods and simply return the resultant task directly.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 You *can*, but *should you*? https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Answer (score 0):

`_studentRepo.GetStudents()` returns a `Task<List<...>>`.

As the error is telling you, `Task` isn't a collection and doesn't have a `Select()` method.

You can use `await` to get the collection inside the task, but you need to call `Select()` on the `await`ed value (your code currently `await`s `Select()`).

You need to add parentheses:

```
(await ...).Select(...);
```

Comment: This answers half of the question. `IEnumerable<T>` does not implement `.ToListAsync()`